# Xamarin.Auth NUGet package not installing

Tags: xamarin, oauth, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin project using .NET Standard 2.0 and i'm trying to authenticate an user via facebook. For that i'm trying to install Xamarin.Auth.

I keep getting these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). 
Package Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0 supports: net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)     
App.Android C:\gitwork\App\App\App.Android\App.Android.csproj   1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). 
Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0) 
App.Android C:\gitwork\App\App\App.Android\App.Android.csproj   1
```

I googled as much as i could and couldn't find an answer how to solve this.

Anyone had this issue and found a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Install the package on your PCL project instead of your Android project

Comment: @iamIcarus didnt thought it would be so simple.. thanks, that works

Comment: glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although i replied this as a comment, since this resolved your issue, 
>   i'm posting it as an answer as well so you can mark it and help others that
>   might miss the comment

Install the package on your PCL project instead of your Android project